# libcurl4-openssl-dev:armhf cannot be installed when libcurl4-openssl-dev is already installed

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling, debian-jessie

I have created a c++ app on Debian Jessie 8.10 amd64 which also need the following libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

I also need to cross compile the source code for armhf. So according to this quite helpful link https://wiki.embeddedarm.com/wiki/Jessie_armhf_Cross_Compile I gave the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install curl build-essential
su root
echo "deb http://emdebian.org/tools/debian jessie main" > 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/emdebian.list
curl http://emdebian.org/tools/debian/emdebian-toolchain-archive.key | apt-key add -
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
apt-get update
apt-get install crossbuild-essential-armhf
```

Everything got installed correctly and then I also gave :

```
 sudo apt-get install libssl-dev:armhf
 sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev:armhf
```

The first command executed successfully. On the other hand the second one failed giving the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
libcurl4-doc:armhf libcurl3-dbg:armhf libidn11-dev:armhf libkrb5-dev:armhf libldap2-dev:armhf
librtmp-dev:armhf libssh2-1-dev:armhf pkg-config:armhf
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libcurl4-openssl-dev:armhf
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
23 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/316 kB of archives.
After this operation, 863 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 94032 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.38.0-4+deb8u8_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl4-openssl-dev:armhf (7.38.0-4+deb8u8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.38.0-4+deb8u8_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/include/curl/curlbuild.h', which is different from other instances of package libcurl4-openssl-dev:armhf
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.38.0-4+deb8u8_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Since I'm quite new in cross compilation procedures does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0) might be useful...

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong. It is a file conflict in related with multiarch packages. It is a [bug in the package](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=913995)

Here is a explanation of this kind of bugs, from https://wiki.debian.org/MultiArch/Hints

> The package in question is marked Multi-Arch: same, but has
>   conflicting versions of at least one file for different architectures.
>   The hint tells the filename (or the number of filenames) and the
>   architectures (or number of architectures) in question. The easiest
>   way to fix is to remove the Multi-Arch: same declaration, but often
>   enough it can be fixed by moving the offending files to
>   per-architecture locations (typically
>   /usr/lib/$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)/). For *-dev packages, the Multi-Arch:
>   same capability often is not critical and removing is a good initial
>   measure.

I just run into the same kind of problem, which still is an issue with some packages. In my case **libcurl-openssl-dev** was replacing the **/usr/bin/curl-config** binary.

To me it required swapping from x64/i386 libraries when i needed cross-compiling but i am well aware it might not be possible for everyone.

Comment: the linked bug reefers to the i386 and amd64 conflict, still is basically the same conflict reported in the question.